# Trying to figure out what this line of code means

Tags: query-string

This code is from a program I use to enter and track information. Numbers are entered as work orders (WO) to track clients. But one of the tables is duplicating the WO information. So I was trying to figure out a general outline of what this code is saying so that the problem can be fixed.

Here is the original line:

```
wc.dll?x3~emproc~datarecord~&ACTION=DISPLAY&TABLE+WORK&KEYVALUE=<%work.wo%&KEYFIELD=WO
```

What I think I understand of it so far, and I could be very wrong, is:

```
wc.dll?x3~emproc~datarecord~&ACTION       
//No clue because don't know ~ means or using & (connects?Action)

=DISPLAY&TABLE+WORK&KEYVALUE              
//Display of contents(what makes it pretty) and the value inside the table at that slot 

=<work.wo%&KEYFIELD                    
//Calling the work from the WO object 

=WO                                    
//is Assigning whatever was placed into the WO field into the left side of the statement
```

Comment: Is this a URL used in your program?

Comment: "The code is from a program I use..." Can you tell us what program?

Comment: What kind of code is this? Where and how is it run? Is it including some library, running as a query, in source somewhere, ...?

Comment: In what language.  It's not a complete expression in either C++ or Java: in both languages, a `?` requires a following `:`. And the sequence `~&` nor `%&` can't occur either: both would imply a unary `&`, which doesn't exist in Java, and which results in a pointer in C++, which isn't a legal operand for either `~` nor `%`.

Comment: The program is called Emaint. It is maintenance management software. This specific bit of code is from the table that prints out and tells me what WO number was assigned automatically to the new job. But I don't want the WO number to print out in this box since it does that already in another area.

Comment: @JamesKanze ...its not code,its a query string ,it gets passed to wc.dll and it contains values of variables ,for example the variable ACTION equals DISPLAY , the standard format of a queriy string is var1=value1&var2=word1+word2&var3=value3 ...

Comment: This is probably not C++ or Java because one `=` means assignment and `==` is for comparison.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know if this is Java, C++, or something else. I was just hoping to get an idea of what the operators where doing. Sorry there isn't much to work with.

Comment: When you read the `Emaint` documentation, what did the Query Language section state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do my best to interpret the statement, with the limited information you've provided:

- `wc.dll` is an instruction to invoke a DLL
- `?` is introducing a list of parameters (like a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) in HTTP)
- `x3~emproc~datarecord~` seems like a reference to a function in the `dll`
- `&` parameter separator
- `ACTION=DISPLAY` set the `ACTION` parameter to the value `DISPLAY`
- `TABLE+WORK` perhaps sets a couple of flags
- `KEYVALUE=<%work.wo%` set the `KEYVALUE` parameter to the value of `<%work.wo%`
- `KEYFIELD=WO` set the `KEYFIELD` parameter to the value `WO`

Hope that helps.